# $_SESSION don't work in include file in php

Tags: php

My website has a very simple structure base on `include` in `php`.

Here the structure:

```
<?
    session_start();
    include("lang/".$_SESSION['lang'].".php");
?>
<html>
<body>
...
<? include("menu.php"); ?>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Content of menu.php is:

```
<div>
My name is <?= $_SESSION['name']; ?>
</div>
```

My problem is in the `menu.php`, the `$_SESSION` don't work anymore.

Is there a reason for that ?

Thanks.

Comment: where do you set `$_SESSION['name']` ?

Comment: You need to set it up before use it. For example, **$_SESSION['name']**, you should set **$_SESSION['name'] = 'name'**; and then you can use it. Otherwise errors reached. Or check it like this: **if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){}**

Comment: Use proper php tag , `<?php ?>`

Comment: Note: my code is deliberately simplified...

Comment: @PacPac where have you set session? :)

Comment: Where is the code for when you login. Typically that is when you assign a Session.

Comment: @PacPac - you're going to have to provide more code than you have. Based on your code, the line in `menu.php` should work... UNLESS you haven't set `name` in your session. Where are you doing so? Are you even doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing the name. That is why it is not shown.
Try this

```
 <div>
My name is <?php echo "$_SESSION['name']"; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know about `<?=` ? This is use to print in php.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry I didnt know that. Thanks for the info.